# How is BAB calculated for a Fused being?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, powers, psionics

How do you calculate the BAB on the fused being created by the [fusion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/fusion.htm) power? If you fuse together two half bab characters does it make a full bab character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You get the best bonus.

Relevant clauses:

1.

> class features are pooled

2.

> this effectively means the fused being uses the better...attack bonus...of either member

The pattern is that bonuses of the same type do not stack, they overlap, and you get the best bonus available to you.  If you have a Psion 20 and a Wilder 20, you get 10 BAB.  If you have a Psion 20 and another Psion 18, you get 10 BAB.  If you have a Psion 20 and a Fighter 14, you get 14 BAB.

Comment: But attack bonus isn't the same as base attack bonus if I understand correctly. So can you use one character's BAB and another character's strength modifier when determining attack bonus or are you restricted to choosing the better attack bonus of the component characters?

Comment: @Cellheim the power explicitly calls that distinction out:  "For each of the six ability scores, the fused being’s score is the higher of yours and the other creature’s".  If the Fused Being's Strength is X, that's what he uses on attack rolls with Melee weapons(unless there's an exception, like weapon finesse)

Comment: So then does the hypothetical creature use the better of the two BABs +  the better of the two strength modifiers + the size modifier to determine attack bonus or is it just the better of the two attack bonuses of the individual creatures?

Comment: The power is unclear on Size modifier.  My personal ruling as an experienced 3.5 DM is that the fused creature is the size of the largest base creature, and would have adjustments for size accordingly.  So, if they were the same size, it'd be Better_of_2_BABs + Better_of_2_Strengths.  If they were different sizes, it'd be Better_of_2_BABs + Better_of_2_Strengths + Larger_Size_Modifier